# Accordion sidebar in spree taxons_tree

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, taxonomy

I am creating an acordion sidebar menu in taxonomies. Everything works good except one thing: When I click on the first parent element it works, and taxons_tree is hidden. But when I click on the second, third and etc, only the first taxons_tree is hidden. Here is my code of _taxonomies.html.erb:

```
<% max_level = Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1 %>

<nav id="taxonomies" class="sidebar-item" data-hook>
  <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
    <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level, @taxon] do %>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class='taxonomy-root'><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#root_taxon"><span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify">
                            </span><%= Spree.t(:shop_by_taxonomy, taxonomy: taxonomy.name) %></a></h4></div></div></div>
      <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, max_level) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

and my taxons_tree method of frontend_helper.rb:

```
def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
  return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.leaf?
  content_tag :div, id:'root_taxon', class: 'list-group panel-collapse collapse in' do
    taxons = root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
      link_to(seo_url(taxon), class: 'list-group-item'){content_tag(:span, " ", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right") + taxon.name} + taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
    end
    safe_join(taxons, "\n")
  end

end
```

I understand that href from _taxonomies.html.erb must be the same with my content_tag id. You can see I tried too use variable, but it works the same only for the first one. It must change for every new taxon, but i dont know how it do right. Source code for acodrdion menu I take from here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-menu maybe it will help you. Here it is implemented very simply just changing #collapseOne, #collapseTwo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

taxomies.erb:

```
  <% max_level = Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1 %>

  <nav id="taxonomies" class="sidebar-item" data-hook>
    <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
     <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level, @taxon] do %>
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default heading" >
                        <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class='taxonomy-root'><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="<%= '#' + taxonomy.root.id.to_s %>"><span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify">
                                </span><%= Spree.t(:shop_by_taxonomy, taxonomy: taxonomy.name) %></a></h4></div></div></div>
          <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, max_level) %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </nav>
```

and frontend_helper.rb:

```
 def taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
       return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.leaf?
          content_tag :div, id:root_taxon.root.id, class: 'list-group panel-collapse collapse in' do
            taxons = root_taxon.children.map do |taxon|
              link_to(seo_url(taxon), class: 'list-group-item'){content_tag(:span, " ", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right") + taxon.name} + taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1)
            end
            safe_join(taxons, "\n")
          end

        end
```